# How to get enabled property of a control?

Tags: delphi, properties

In Delphi it is possible to get the process name and class name of any control which is clicked system wide via windows api.

process name:

```
GetWindowThreadProcessId(Hwnd, ProcessId)
```

by process ID one can get to the process name

class name:

```
SetLength(ClassName, 255);
SetLength(ClassName, GetClassName(Hwnd, pchar(ClassName), 255));
```

Is there an easy way similar to the ones mentioned above to get a control's enabled property? (without using UIAutomation)

Comment: Is the control windowed?

Comment: the control could be any editable control (e.g. TMemo, TEdit, but also custom edit controls)

Comment: @Airogat the question is if it is object of Windows GDI, if it has its dedicated HWND handle. If it does - then search the function quote by TLama in MSDN

Comment: Yes, I asked if the control was windowed or not. If you don't understand what that question means then it is likely that you are in the process of making some wrong decisions. That's not meant in a dismissive way, but I suspect that you are not aware that you lack the necessary knowledge to take decisions in this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the window handle for a control, then the `IsWindowEnabled` function will tell you whether it is enabled.

Keep in mind that that is acting on the window at the API level, *not* the Delphi VCL level. In Delphi, there can be controls that do not have window handles (anything that descends from `TGraphicControl`, which includes `TLabel` and `TSpeedButton`), so `IsWindowEnabled` obviously can't tell you anything about those controls.

Delphi does not provide any facility for querying information about arbitrary Delphi controls from other processes. If you need something like that, then you'll have to arrange for the external process to respond to commands of your choosing. That is, you will need to be in control of both programs so that you can put code in them both to cooperate.

If `GetWindowThreadProcessId` and `GetClassName` are already telling you the information you want, then `IsWindowEnabled` will work just fine because they all have the same limitation regarding Delphi VCL controls.